# time complexity of closed hashing algorithm

Tags: hashtable, time-complexity

Assume we have applied **close hashing** algorithm on (4, 2, 12, 3, 9, 11, 7, 8, 13, and 18). And assume the length of hash table is **7** initially.
How a search on such a hash table can be achieved in **O(1)** time in the worst case.

Answer (score 0):

It really doesn't matter what you do. Because the data set is predetermined, there is a constant upper bound to the worst case lookup for any hash function (as long as the hash function is guaranteed to terminate). (If one element takes longer to find than the others, that is the upper bound.) The constant upper bound implies O(1) complexity. QED.

Comment: so you mean always the time complexity of close hashing is O(1)? or I  misunderstand?

Comment: @user2076685 No. Time complexity is a function of some variable(s). Your question doesn't include anything that might vary. There is no N so any possible function of N, such as N^2 or log(N) or just plain N is excluded. The remaining possibility, aside from a non-terminating program, is O(1).

Comment: Actually i'm confused. it was exam question! Could you please tell me how can I answer this question. I'm new in this subject. could you please explain it simpler?

Comment: @user2076685 Sorry, your teacher made an error. You have to be psychic, or at least attend class to be able to recite whatever example the question is supposed to reference. The basic idea behind my answer is a common mistake for teachers as they try to simplify a question, but accidentally remove one too many variables. Unfortunately, in this case there's just too much missing. I really can't tell what the heck he's thinking, or what the answer is supposed to be. Are you supposed to suggest a hash function? No idea.